# Doctrine HasLifecycleCallbacks PrePersist|PreUpdate don't fire

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 with ZF2 and the Doctrine-Module.
I've written an Entity that needs a PreUpdate|PrePersist, because Doctrine doesn't allow
Date|Datetime in a primary key:

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="sample")
 */
class Sample
{

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $runmode;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $date;


    public function getRunmode()
    {
        return $this->runmode;
    }

    public function setRunmode($runmode)
    {
        $this->runmode = $runmode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    protected function formatDate()
    {
        die('preUpdate, prePersist');
        if ($this->date instanceof \DateTime) {
            $this->date = $this->date->format('Y-m-d');
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

The Problem is now, if i set a DateTime as a Date I get the message:

```
"Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"
```

because it doesn't walk into the formatDate.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, since you mapped the field `Sample#date` as `datetime`, it should always be either `null` or an instance of `DateTime`.

Therefore, you should typehint your `setDate` method as following:

```php
public function setDate(\DateTime $date = null)
{
    $this->date = $date;
    return $this;
}
```

Also, your [lifecycle callback](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) is not invoked because the visibility of method `formatDate` is `protected`, therefore not accessible by the ORM. Change it into `public` and it will work. No conversion should be necessary anyway, so you can get rid of it.

Comment: The `ORM:PrePersist` is simply ignored in my case... Did you register some services or something else?

Comment: @Ron it's a callback. It must be public and it must be registered in metadata.

Comment: thanks! but how do i register it in metadata? never seen this before... or it's maybe trival?

Comment: ok, stupidest mistake ever :D thanks for your help, it now seems to work. I use this solution in my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894716/zend-framework-2-register-event-listener