# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 - Created at timestamp field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, timestamp, zend-framework2, event-listener

I want to create a custom `created_at` annotation in `ZF2`. I found a [(German) tutorial](http://www.scandio.de/2012/02/symfony2-custom-annotations/) how to build such an annotation in Symfony2.

Everything seems easy to copy except the registering of the `prePersist` listener.

The code in Symfony is:

```
services:
created_at_listener:
    class: Scandio\Annotations\Driver\CreatedAtDriver
    tags:
      - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist}
    arguments: [@annotation_reader]
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this in Zend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thanks to Ocramius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15066591/1331671) I found a different solution for creating a `PrePersist` created at timestamp:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * ...
*/
class ChangeRequest

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Form\Attributes({"type":"text"})
     * @Form\Options({"label":"Created at"})
     * @Form\Exclude()
     */
    protected $created_at;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function timestamp()
        {
        if(is_null($this->getCreatedAt())) {
            $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Easier solution:

```
class ChangeRequest
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Form\Attributes({"type":"text"})
     * @Form\Options({"label":"Created at"})
     * @Form\Exclude()
     */
    protected $created_at;

    ...
}
```

without costly event functionality.